# How to get char* from char**

Tags: c, string, pointers, char, printf

I understand that & is used to reference the address of object so `&char* = char**`. Is there anyway to reverse this so that I can get `char*` from `char**`?

So I have:

```
char** str; //assigned to and memory allocated somewhere

printf ("%s", str); //here I want to print the string.
```

How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use the [**dereference operator**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference_operator).

The *dereference operator* operates on a pointer variable, and returns an l-value equivalent to the value at the pointer address. This is called "dereferencing" the pointer.

```
char** str; //assigned to and memory allocated somewhere

printf ("%s", *str); //here I want to print the string.
```

Answer (score 5):

Dereference `str`:

```
print ("%s", *str); /* assuming *str is null-terminated */
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have a `T*` (called a pointer to an object of type `T`) and want to get a `T` (an object of type T), you can use the operator `*`. It returns the object pointed by your pointer.

In this case you've got a pointer to an object of type `char*` (that's it: `(char*)*`) so you can use `*`.

Another way could be that of using operator `[]`, the one you use to access the arrays. `*s` is equal to `s[0]`, while `s[n]` equals `*(s+n)`.

If your `char** s` is an array of `char*`, by using `printf( "%s", *str )` you'll print the first one only. In this case it's probably easier to read if you use `[]`:

```
for( i = 0; i < N; ++ i ) print( "%s\n", str[i] );
```

Althought it's semantically equivalent to:

```
 for( i = 0; i < N; ++ i ) print( "%s\n", *(str+i) );
```